# array.prototype.flat is undefined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Given is the following js command:

```
[].flat;
```

Executing it in a browser (chrome/firefox): returns `function`

Executing it with nodejs v10.13.0: returns `undefined`

Now I am wondering what other methods are not in the node RTE and where the documentation of global Objects like `Array` is.

Seems to be the same with `Array.prototype.flatMap`.

Comment: Those are "proposal" stage APIs.

Comment: MDN documents this stuff. For example, scroll to the bottom comparability table for [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: Great source to check nodejs versions and features table https://node.green/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You'll need [node 11 or higher for `Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). MDN is a great resource both for learning about Javascript and as a reference. You will find information about usage, browser compatibility, and even polyfills there.

As for Node.js support of ES6+, the best resource is [node.green](https://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--Array-prototype--flat--flatMap--Array-prototype-flat) with a very detailed and up to date list of supported features by node version.

Answer (score 12):

It doesn't seem to be supported in node.js at the moment. A quick ES6 way of flattening (depth 1) an array:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].reduce((acc, val) => [ ...acc, ...val ], [])
```

Comment: This will raise an Error with arrays that have elements that are not arrays. Examples: `[2, 3, [1, 2]]`,  `[2, 3]`. In addition to this, it will also produce not desirable results if elements are `Strings`. Use this instead to flatten Arrays up to 1 level in ES6: `[[1, 2], [3, 4], 2].reduce((flattened, element) => flattened.concat(element), []);`

Answer (score 4):

Not yet defined in node js but you can rewrite it easily

```js
function flatten(array)
{
    if(array.length == 0)
        return array;
    else if(Array.isArray(array[0]))
        return flatten(array[0]).concat(flatten(array.slice(1)));
    else
        return [array[0]].concat(flatten(array.slice(1)));
}

console.log(flatten([1, 3, [4, 8, 8], [[6],[3,5,[9,9]]]]))
```

Answer (score 3):

To build off of Daphoque's answer (which is equivalent to `flat(Infinity)`, I believe), you could do a full polyfill like this.

```
if (!Array.prototype.flat) {
    Array.prototype.flat = function (maxDepth, currentDepth) {
        "use strict";
        var array = this;
        maxDepth = maxDepth === Infinity
            ? Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
            : parseInt(maxDepth, 10) || 1;
        currentDepth = parseInt(currentDepth, 10) || 0;

        // It's not an array or it's an empty array, return the object.
        if (!Array.isArray(array) || !array.length) {
            return array;
        }

        // If the first element is itself an array and we're not at maxDepth, 
        // flatten it with a recursive call first.
        // If the first element is not an array, an array with just that element IS the 
        // flattened representation.
        // **Edge case**: If the first element is an empty element/an "array hole", skip it.
        // (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Examples)
        var firstElemFlattened = (Array.isArray(array[0]) && currentDepth < maxDepth)
            ? array[0].flat(maxDepth, currentDepth + 1)
            : array[0] === undefined ? [] : [array[0]];

        return firstElemFlattened.concat(array.slice(1).flat(maxDepth, currentDepth));
    };
}
```

And here are some poorly named Jasmine tests based on the [examples on the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Examples):

```
// MDN examples:
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Examples
describe('testing flatmap against mdn examples', function () {
  "use strict";

  // loadFolders,
  it('works 1', function () {
    var arr1 = [1, 2, [3, 4]];
    var out = arr1.flat();
    expect(out).toEqual([1, 2, 3, 4]);
  });

  it('works 2', function () {
    var arr2 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
    var out2 = arr2.flat();
    expect(out2).toEqual([1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6]]);
  });

  it('works 3', function () {
    var arr3 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
    var out3 = arr3.flat(2);
    expect(out3).toEqual([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
  });

  it('works 4', function () {
    var arr4 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6, [7, 8, [9, 10]]]]];
    var out4 = arr4.flat(Infinity);
    expect(out4).toEqual([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
  });

  it('works 5', function () {
    var arr5 = [1, 2, , 4, 5];
    var out5 = arr5.flat();
    expect(out5).toEqual([1, 2, 4, 5]);
  });

  it('works 6', function () {
    var arr6 = [1, 2, , 4, [5, 6]];
    var out6 = arr6.flat();
    expect(out6).toEqual([1, 2, 4, 5, 6]);
  });
});
```

I'm surprised that I didn't find a polyfill for [`flat` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) like [they have for, eg, `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill), but this one does seem to pass the examples there.

Let me know if I've missed a case.